# Matlab: Simple Index Out of Bounds

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I can't figure out why I'm getting out of bounds. Here is the error:

Attempted to access t2(3638); index out of bounds because numel(t2)=3637.
    Error in problem1testing (line 25)
    hile(t2(index))<3600

```
   dt2=.99;
     t2=(0:dt2:3600);    
   index = 1;
while(t2(index))<3600
A2(index+1)=A2(index)-dt2*(La*A2(index));
B2(index+1)=B2(index)+dt2*((La*A2(index+1)*ab)-(Lb*B2(index)));
C2(index+1)=C2(index)+dt2*((Lb*B2(index+1)*bc)-(Lc*C2(index)));
D2(index+1)=D2(index)+dt2*(Lc*C2(index));
E2(index+1)=E2(index)+dt2*((La*A2(index+1)*ae)+(Lb*B2(index+1)*be))-(Le*E2(index));
F2(index+1)=F2(index)+dt2*(Le*E2(index+1));
index = index +1;
end
```

I have searched and found that it has to do with my initilization of t2 but this is the length it is supposed to be and I am using code very similar to my instructor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your while-condition is `while (t2(index))<3600`, but the index should obviously be limited to the length of `t2`. Use `while index<numel(t2)` instead.

Besides this, your loop has a fixed number of iterations. In these cases, a for-loop is better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no MATLAB expert, but the fact that you are hitting 3628 indicates to me that your while loop is set up incorrectly. Have you tried something like:

```
while((t2(index))<3600)
```

I'm afraid it may be inspecting t2(index) to make the true/false determination. Or do you mean to be checking the index value and not the value of t2(index)?

```
while (index<3600)
```

Comment: that didn't work. thanks tho. yeah i cant figure out why its hitting 3628, ive tried inspecting output =/